# How do I set an unlimited textwidth in Vim?

Tags: vim, text-width

In Vim, I don't want to have a text width at all. I would like lines to go on forever. I tried `set textwidth=0` but `fq` will still wrap the lines up to a certain number. The only way I can do this now is to set `textwidth` to a very large (but not too large) number. Is there a way to say that I want an unlimited text width?

Comment: Try vi.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 4):

Setting `textwidth` to 0 is the right way to not have a limit on the text width.  As for `gq`, it's documented that it uses the screen width if `textwidth` is set to 0.

If you want to just join lines and not wrap them at all, then you can just use `J` instead of `gq`, which will join the lines into one line, and may provide what you're looking for in terms of formatting.

Comment: `J` doesn't quite do what I want, i.e., `gq` with `tw=999999` (or some very large number). I can see the difference in the comment lines being joined to normal lines with `J`, which doesn't happen with `gq`. Perhaps the answer then is just to set `tw` to a very large number.